# What's wrong with update & destroy entities in Kendo scheduler

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I was trying to use Kendo scheduler with a bundle of ASP.NET MVC Web API. Client side performed as Angular JS application. Server side: for read I'm using odata controller for create/update/delete actions Web API controller.

I have three issues with configuration of scheduler:

1. When I try to send model for create & update it will not send one model, but send a bundle of it

   {"models":[{"Id":0,"Title":"No title","StartDate":"2015-04-28T11:00:00.000Z","EndDate":"2015-04-28T11:30:00.000Z","StartTimezone":"","EndTimezone":"","Description":"","RecurrenceID":0,"RecurrenceRule":"","RecurrenceException":"","IsAllDay":false,"OwnerID":0},{"Id":0,"Title":"No title","StartDate":"2015-04-28T13:00:00.000Z","EndDate":"2015-04-28T13:30:00.000Z","StartTimezone":"","EndTimezone":"","Description":"","RecurrenceID":0,"RecurrenceRule":"","RecurrenceException":"","IsAllDay":false,"OwnerID":0}]}
2. My update method send data to "api/Schedule/CreateEvent", instead of correct way "api/Schedule/UpdateEvent"
3. My delete method send data to "api/Schedule/CreateEvent", instead of correct way "api/Schedule/DeleteEvent/"

Is anybody can help me?

Angular Code:

```
$scope.schedulerOptions = {
                date: new Date("2015/04/28"),
                dateHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("<strong>#=kendo.toString(date, 'd/M')#</strong>"),
                height: 600,
                views: [
                    //"day",
                    {
                        type: "workWeek",
                        selected: true,
                    },
                    //"week",
                    //"month",
                ],
                timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                dataSource: {
                    batch: true,
                    type: 'odata',
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "odata/ScheduleOData",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        },
                        update: {
                            url: "api/Schedule/UpdateEvent",
                            type: "Post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        },
                        create: {
                            url: "api/Schedule/CreateEvent",
                            type: "Post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        },
                        destroy: {
                            url: function (data) {
                                return "api/Schedule/DeleteEvent/" + data.Id;
                            },
                            type: "Delete",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        },
                        //parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                        //    return JSON.stringify(data);
                        //}
                        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                            if (operation == "destroy") {
                                return;// kendo.stringify(data);
                            }
                            var d = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(data, operation);
                            delete d.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter    
                            delete d.$callback;
                            return d;
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Id",
                            fields: {
                                taskId: { from: "Id", type: "number" },
                                title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                                start: { type: "date", from: "StartDate" },
                                end: { type: "date", from: "EndDate" },
                                startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                                endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                                description: { from: "Description" },
                                recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID", defaultValue: 0 },
                                recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                                recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                                isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" },
                                ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 0 }
                            }
                        },
                        data: function (response) {
                            return response['value'];
                        },
                        total: function (response) {
                            return response['odata.count'];
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
```

Web API Code:

```
public class ScheduleController : ApiController {
        private readonly ISubjectsService _subjectsService;
        private readonly IGenericService _genericService;
        private readonly IMembershipService membership;
        private readonly IMappingEngine mapper;

        public ScheduleController(ISubjectsService subjectsService, IGenericService igs, IMappingEngine mapper, IMembershipService membership) {
            this._subjectsService = subjectsService;
            this._genericService = igs;
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.membership = membership;
        }

        public void UpdateEvent(RootObject model) {
            // some logic
        }

        public void CreateEvent(RootObject model) {
            // some logic
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public void DeleteEvent(int key) {
            // some logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: regarding the update and delete mis-routing - can you double-check the network requests the `data source` is issuing (F12 browser tools) - it's not clear if it's because the `data source` itself is issuing incorrect requests for these operations, or because the actual routing in the `WebAPI` is not working correctly. For example - you have the same model parameter on `UpdateEvent` and `CreateEvent` so I would expect you'd at least need one to be `HttpPost` and another `HttpPut`, or else routing probably won't work (unless you have explicit routes defined?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason multiple models get sent is probably because the datasource's batch mode is set to true; if you change this

```
 batch: true,
```

to this

```
 batch: false,
```

it should send the creates/updates individually (see [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch) for details)

I'm not sure it's what you need, but if it's the case that you want to send a *single* model that contains an array of sub-models for example, you can do something like this:

```
 parameterMap: function (data, operation) {

   if (operation=="create" || operation=="update"){
      var rootModel = {rootProperty:"foo",models:[]};
       data.models.forEach(function(model)){
           //do whatever transformation of the individual models here
           //and add to the aggregate model.
           rootModel.models.push(model);
       }
       return rootModel; //whatever you return from parameterMap is what will be sent in the HTTP request.
     }
     //rest of your special operation cases here                     
  }
```

In that case you probably do want to keep `batch:true`.

As for the other issues - more information is needed, see the comments I posted - you might be better off with a separate question for these :)

Comment: If I change from true to false, it will send 4 multiply requests to "api/Schedule/CreateEvent" on update action

Comment: You mean when batch is false, and you update a single item, it's sending 4 separate requests for the same object?

Comment: nope its send 4 separate requests for all 4 objects, but must send only one request, this is the first issue

Comment: Is it that you want all of the modified objects sent in one request but as some kind of aggregate model as opposed to an array of individual models? I'm not sure the data source can do that automatically, you probably need to handle this in the `parameterMap` function; you can loop through `data.models` and build a single object from them or whatever you need to do.

Comment: oh if i know how to do this

Comment: @BorHunter - see updated answer, does that help at all?